# Button error in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I made a Command Button in Excel with the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim a As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim q As Integer

z=0
q=0

If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
  z = z + 1
Else
  q = 0
End If

If z = 1 Then
  ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=True
Else
  If q = 0 Then
    a = MsgBox("?????", vbYesNo)
    If a = vbNo Then
      Cancel = True
    Else: ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=True
    End If
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

and I'm getting this

[image]

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct : Procedure declaration does not match description of event.

The [CommandButton control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/click-event-commandbutton-control-accelerator-caption-properties-example)
VBA event routine does not have parameters. It should be:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click ()
```

Comment: The error will then ly with `If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then`

Comment: All `Target` references will cause errors - this isn't the way to use a command button. My above link contains an example that may help.

Comment: I will take read on my lunch break

Comment: @harrymc i understand, but how do i make the code here work then?

Comment: @harrymc as in, how do i make a button that has a code that uses excel's function of finding if a cell has been changed or not?

Comment: See for example [this article](https://excelvbatutor.com/index.php/excel-vba-lesson-5-sub-procedure-functions/) that may answer your question. I would like to help, but  some study is still required. Posting too many questions here you risk moderator intervention. There exist an enormous amount of information about VBA, google is your friend. Some known websites are [site1](https://www.guru99.com/vba-tutorial.html), [site2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/index.htm) and [site3](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html).

Comment: thank you so much @harrymc

Answer (score 0):

You have a Command Button with a parameter of Target. This is something that is not possible, and as such you are getting an error.

You have to remove that part, and aquire the selected cell using `worksheet.activecell` instead, or `selection.target`. But it has been a while since I did VBA coding and I currently don't have VBA handy, so I cannot provide the correct code right now.